# How the server knows the port number of the client in which it will use it to send the responses to the client using java programming socket?

Tags: java, sockets

In socket programming using java , we need to specify in the client side the port number in which it will communicate through it with the server using the socket class . On the other hand , in the server side , we don't need to specify the client port number through which we will send our responses to the client , we just create a port number through which we will listen to the request and we just wait for this request to arrive using the accept () method. So please someone explains how the responses are sent from server to clients although we don't specify the client port number ?

Comment: If *my* client decides to communicate via port 1300 but my neighbour chooses 27364 then both should work, the server must not know beforehand what client port to communicate to, that is something that is different per request.

Comment: Wasn't this same question asked yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

Both TCP port numbers are in every TCP segment.  When the incoming TCP connection is accepted at the server, the server (specifically the TCP protocol implementation in the server) knows all it needs to know to respond to the client.

Comment: Ok , but is there is any function in socket programming  responsible for opening or creating a client n port and sending it with the TCP segment ? I mean how exactly the port number is created .

Comment: If you don't explicitly bind an address (=port, for TCP) to the interface, then one is arbitrarily chosen when you issue the connect call.  Generally speaking, the client side should **not** use an explicit port number.

Comment: "*Generally speaking, the client side should **not** use an explicit port number*" - UNLESS the network architecture, or the communication protocol, dictates that a specific port be used.